# Android studio does not compile permission in manifest

Tags: android, android-studio

I bumped into a very strange problem, the studio compiles all the manifest permissions except one:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Tested in other compilers - the permissions successfully compiled.
How can you solve this truly strange problem?
My full list of permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: How did you verify the compilation success, with android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Comment: what is *to compile a permission* to begin with? Are you getting any build errors?

Comment: Precisely, explain this process?

Comment: I do not get any errors at compile time, but the compiled manifest does not have this permission

Comment: can you post this compiled manifest?

Comment: I havent idea what the magic is, but now everything works with any parameters targetSdkVersion. So unfortunately I can not provide an old manifest.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue what was happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by modifying the build.gradle file.
I changed targetSdkVersion from 26 to 19 (any version that <19)
But I'm not sure if this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

> If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen. The app requests the user's approval by sending an intent with action ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION. The app can check whether it has this authorization by calling Settings.canDrawOverlays().

Comment: [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Comment: but other compilers successfully compile this permission. So how can the studio compile this permission?

Comment: They are probably still targeting below 23

Comment: my thoughts exactly, can you post the sdk versions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, because it has signature protection level.

See [signature protection level - clarifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438129/signature-protection-level-clarifying)
and see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Also you cannot use BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE permission, it has signature protection level too.