# Acquiring Android Permission with Signature Protection Level

Tags: android

According to android developer documents, permissions with `signature` protection level in app `A` can be acquired if calling application `B` is signed with same key that `A` is signed. Also according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21438942/5199226), **android** permissions with `signature` protection level can not be acquired by third-party applications but in [android developer documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES), there is a permission named `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` with `signature` as protection level. I've seen many codes declaring this permission in their codes:

```
<uses-permission android:name="REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

So how it's possible? What's missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So how it's possible?

It is possible for them to have that element in their manifest because their developers were capable of typing it in.

Just because an app has a `<uses-permission>` element does not mean that they get the permission. That depends on a lot of factors, including the `protectionLevel`.

In the specific case of `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`, that does not have a `signature` value for `protectionLevel`. It has `signature|appop`. The `appop` is a confusing value, but it boils down to "there are odd ways in which the app can exercise the permission". In this case, the package installer on Android 8.0+ will reject outright any app that does not request this permission and tries to use `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`. Otherwise, it will prompt the user to confirm that it is OK for this app to request to install packages.

Note: the `|appop` part does not appear in the JavaDocs, but it does in the platform manifest, which is what matters at runtime.

Comment: How did you find out that protection level is `signature|appop` not `signature`? Do you the meaning of `appop` ? Nothing mentioned about it in the documents.

Comment: @MehranTorki: "How did you find out that protection level is signature|appop" -- I looked at the platform manifest file, where these permissions get defined. For example, [here is Android 9.0's platform manifest and the definition of `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-9.0_r3/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L2990-L2993). "Do you the meaning of appop ?" -- as I wrote in the answer,"there are odd ways in which the app can exercise the permission". These do not behave like ordinary `dangerous` runtime permissions, for example.