# Unable to retrieve if REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is granted for other apps

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get a list of apps (on Android 8.0+) that have `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permissions marked as **granted**.

```
context.packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS or PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).forEach { pi ->
    if (pi.requestedPermissions != null) {
        for (i in pi.requestedPermissions.indices) {
            if (pi.requestedPermissions[i] == android.Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) {
                if ((pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] and PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0) {
                    // permission is granted, do stuff here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that corresponding `requestedPermissionsFlags` entry is **always** 1, which means `REQUESTED_PERMISSION_REQUIRED` and that is obviously wrong.

I tried different api: `context.packageManager.checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, pi.packageName) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` with the same result.

In tried this on Android 8, 9 and 10 on different devices and the only success I had was on Pixel 3a that came positive for `com.android.nfc`. Others were always false even when I can see in system settings that chrome and other apps have this permission granted.

Am I missing something for this API? Is it private? There is not much to find about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this permmission has a `signature` protection level. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element):

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission

So `requestedPermissionsFlags` is correct -  only `com.android.nfc` is granted.

Actually `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` has a `signature|appop` protection level, that's why not only system apps can use it although this perrmission is not granted for them. For a little bit more details - [Acquiring Android Permission with Signature Protection Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180471/acquiring-android-permission-with-signature-protection-level).